# how to fix Image tag protocol error in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

i follow this course: https://courses.nativescripting.com/courses/nativescript-core-getting-started-guide/lectures/2564661
I tried to follow and my code is:

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded">
  <ActionBar title="My App" class="action-bar"></ActionBar>
  <!-- Your UI components go here -->
  <Image src="~\images\apple.jpg" ></Image>
</Page>
```

but it not show the picture in android emulator and some message error:

```
JS: Error in downloadBitmap - java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: HellWorld\app\images\apple.jpg
```

Comment: try using forward-slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images in {N} are usually processed with tags such as:

```
src="res://apple"
```

See `https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/image-resources`

Comment: so if my path is

  C:\VSCode-Workspace\HellWorld\app\images\apple.jpg

what is src now ? my project name is HellWorld

Comment: If you choose not to use image resources, you could try something like 

    <Image src="~/images/apple.jpg" />

but you won't get the scaling you'd want for different screen resolutions.  And, you may have to deal with imagesource properties.  I've always used image respources, so I don't have any working code I can just paste in.